# SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail Anonymous User

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, email, api, sharepoint-email, outgoing-email

I have a public website made with on premise sharepoint. Can I use rest api (SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail) to send email with anonymous user? I am trying but didn't work.

Comment: Did you disable the **Require Use Remote Interfaces permission** in Site Settings > Site Permissions > Anonymous Access?

Comment: @Mihail-FlorinPopa I checked and this is disabled :/

Comment: What value did you use for the **From** property?

Comment: I use "portal@companyname.com.br", the was like this: 'From': "portal@companyname.com.br". Here the code I use to reference: https://gist.github.com/BasantPandey/05189832546f2c6cc0bd008fcfec3264

Comment: May I suggest that you update your question to include as many details as possible about your SP configuration, code snippets, error messages and what you have tried so far. This will help other people to look at your question and attempt to answer it. Otherwise we may continue to have unfruitful back-and-forths...

Comment: @Mihail-FlorinPopa Ok, thanks man!